# Can someone tell me how to remove parentheses from an answer?

Tags: python

When it outputs the answer for this, it puts them in parentheses. Can someone help me remove them?

Code:

```
n=int(input())
def rev(steps,n):
    sum = n + int(str(n)[::-1])
    if str(sum) == str(sum)[::-1]:
        return (steps,sum)
    else:
        return rev(steps+1,sum)

print(rev(1,n))
```

If I input 87, it would output something like (4,4884), which is correct, but I just need to remove the parentheses

Comment: Why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: It returns a tuple. The presence of the `()` is entirely superfluous

Answer (score 1):

```
n=int(input())
def rev(steps,n):
    sum = n + int(str(n)[::-1])
    if str(sum) == str(sum)[::-1]:
        return (steps,sum)
    else:
        return rev(steps+1,sum)

print(*rev(1,n), sep=', ')
```

Will print `4, 4884` with input `87`

Comment: @noe No problem. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: seems that noe doesnt give you the accepted answer, but Im going to give a usefull answer.